# How to add timeline report in webdriver.io

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io, wdio-v5, wdio-v4

How can I add timeline report in webdriver.io project.

Sample report screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/QualityOps/wdio-timeline-reporter#readme

Step 1: Add wdio-timeline-reporter in dev dependency `"wdio-timeline-reporter": "^5.1.1"`

```
npm i wdio-timeline-reporter --save-dev
```

Step 2: Add timeline in services of the wdio config file

[image]

Step 3: Add timeline in the reporters for wdio config along with output directory for report.

[image]

Step 4: Run your tests and you will report generated in output directory.
[image]